# Chaining three queries in a promise

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

How would I chain these 3 queries together in a promise? And also would they be running one after the other or in parallel?

```
SELECT * FROM books where book_id = $1

SELECT * FROM username where username = $2

SELECT * FROM saved where saved_id = $3
```

Edited:

I don't know what I should return for the function `getBookIdQuery`. It gives the error:

> getBookIdQuery is not a function

```
function getBookIdQuery(){
    return client.query(getBookId, [bookId]);
 }
```

So what should I return for that function in order for my chaining to work?

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {



        getBookIdQuery
        .then(data => {


        })
        .catch(err => {
            reject(err);
        });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which database you are using. But in a general, you can execute your queries either in serial or parallel which ever the way you want.

```
Serial:

async serial(){
    queryResult1 = await client.query('SELECT * FROM books where book_id = $1', ['bookid']);
    queryResult2 = await client.query('SELECT * FROM username where username = $2',['username']);
    queryResult3 = await client.query('SELECT * FROM saved where saved_id = $3',['saved_id']);
    console.log(queryResult1);
    console.log(queryResult2);
    console.log(queryResult3);
}


Parallerl:

async parallel(){
   Promise.all([client.query('SELECT * FROM books where book_id = $1', ['bookid']), client.query('SELECT * FROM username where username = $2',['username']), client.query('SELECT * FROM saved where saved_id = $3',['saved_id']))
   .then(queryResults => {
        console.log(queryResults[0]);
        console.log(queryResults[1]);
        console.log(queryResults[2]);
   })
}
```

Comment: I'm using postgresql and this kinda answers my 2nd question, but I'm still confused. Does the default promise statement run everything asynchronously?

Comment: What do you mean by " Does the default promise statement run everything asynchronously?"?. Promise is not a statement. It is an object which stores result of an asynchronous operation.

Comment: doSomething()
.then(function(result) {
  return doSomethingElse(result);
})
.then(function(newResult) {
  return doThirdThing(newResult);
})
.then(function(finalResult) {
  console.log('Got the final result: ' + finalResult);
})
.catch(failureCallback);

Comment: Yes, this would be async and one way to run your promises in series by chaining them.

Comment: Does this mean the queries would run in parallel in the database then? I thought postgres couldn't have multiple queries running at same time

Comment: Two things here to know
1.  your 'doSomething', 'doSomethingElse', 'doThirdThing' must return promise.
2. Once 'doSomething' is resolved, only then 'doSomethingElse' is executed. Once 'doSomethingElse' is resolved only then 'doThirdThing' is executed.

Unless your 'doSomething' is completed, nodejs wont even post your 'doSomethingElse' query to database in this case

Answer (score 0):

Use **UNION** and value must have the same alias in each Select like:

```
SELECT id as value FROM books where book_id = $1
union
SELECT name as value FROM username where username = $2
union
SELECT identificator as value FROM saved where saved_id = $3
```

Comment: this is good, but im just using queries to substitute because I want to learn how to chain with promises

Comment: ok, this is only simple connestion more select result to one table